# how to run developed application on asus tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, usb-drive

I developed an android application and tested on Samsung mobile phone. then i tried to run that application on asus tablet. but it couldn't install the USB drivers correctly.

Can anyone helped me to run this application on asus tablet?

Comment: you should install "AdbDriverInstaller" software on your pc it will work for all device

Answer (score 1):

There are various method, one of them, You may be try this:
The simplest way to enable USB Debugging. Download **[ADB Toggle](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adbdriver.adbtoggle)** from Google Play.  and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an ASUS tablet as well, and the drivers installed without a hitch for me. You could try to manually install the USB drivers: http://support.asus.com/download/options.aspx?SLanguage=en Hope that helps, if not, come on back.

Comment: yea i already download that driver but i don't know how to configure it to my pc